# JQuery show/hide items based on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page on my site which will show all parks within a region by default. I would then like it to only show specific items based on a clicked region and hide all the other parks.

So far I have 3 regions with and id e.g. region-1, region-2 and region-3 I would then like it to show only parks within those regions so if I clicked on the id of region-1 it would only show the parks with the class of region-1 and hide all the others, this is the same for the other regions.

My biggest problem with getting this to work is that the client will be able to add more regions in the future and more parks to those new regions.

So what I need is JQuery to pick up every region id which will be added in the future and pair them with the relevant parks.

```
<div id="side-bar" class="pull-left">
    <h2>Parks By Region</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li>
            <a href="#region-1">South East England</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#region-2">South West England</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#region-3">North Wales</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="contentWrapper">     

        <h1>REGION TEXT</h1>
        <div class="region-1 pull-left">Park 1</div>
        <div class="region-2 pull-left">Park 2</div>
        <div class="region-3 pull-left">Park 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JSFiddle to help give you an idea of what I'm talking about... http://jsfiddle.net/y9CV9/

Comment: can you provide some jquery code to show us what you tried so far?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/53qXh/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny if you can explain this `$($(this).attr('href')).show();`

Comment: @Bhavik I changed the `region-1` to an id now the anchors href is the id selector for the element to be shown.. `$(this).attr('href')` return `#region-1` so `$($(this).attr('href'))` will return the element to be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use `data-*` instead since it's easier for you to manage:

```
<div id="side-bar" class="pull-left">
    <h2>Parks By Region</h2>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
           <li>
                <a data-region="region-1" href="#region-1">South East England</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a data-region="region-2" href="#region-2">South West England</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-region="region-3" href="#region-3">North Wales</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

then you can use:

```
$('#contentWrapper div').hide();
$('#side-bar a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var region = $(this).attr('data-region');
    $('#contentWrapper div.' + region).show().siblings('div').hide();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y9CV9/22/)**

Comment: This is actually probably the best solution. It's more semantic and there will be more parks per region so using a class instead of an id works in favour. I also removed the #region-1 etc and just gave an empty href which also works in favour as it stops the page moving around when clicking.

I just want to say thank you for your time on this, it has helped A LOT!. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="contentWrapper">     
        <h1>REGION TEXT</h1>
        <div id="region-1" class="region pull-left">Park 1</div>
        <div id="region-2" class="region pull-left">Park 2</div>
        <div id="region-3" class="region pull-left">Park 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $regions = $('#contentWrapper .region').hide();
    $('#side-bar a').click(function(){
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')).show();
        $regions.not($target).hide()
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/53qXh/)

Comment: Instead of doing $($(this).attr('href')) you could do $(this.hash).

Comment: Also, you should cancel the default behavior so the page doesn't jump to the ID when the location fragment changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this makes sense and has worked. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2):

First you have to hide all of your divisions initially then you cn change its attributes on click.

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $regions = $('#contentWrapper .region').hide(); //Hide all div initially
    $('#side-bar a').click(function(){ //find the anchor tag
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')).show(); //change the attribute of current div 
        $regions.not($target).hide()
    })
})
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9BqZa/)**

Comment: Cheers for your answer, it's the same as Arun's, but I think you both answered at very close times. Your answer has been helpful so thank you. :)